# Variable not changing on INotifyPropertyChanged WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code:

```
private ObservableCollection<MatchesViewModel> matches;
private ObservableCollection<string> listWithLists;
private string directoryName = "currentMatches";

private void HandleLoadListClicked(object obj)
{
    directoryName = selectedItem;
    matches = DataGetterAndSetter.GetMatches("Lists\\" + directoryName + ".xml");
    MainPage window = new MainPage();
    window.Show();
}

public IEnumerable<MatchesViewModel> Matches
{
    get
    {
        matches = DataGetterAndSetter.GetMatches("Lists\\"+ directoryName + ".xml");
        return this.matches;
    }
    set
    {
        if (matches == null)
        {
            matches = new ObservableCollection<MatchesViewModel>();
        }
        matches.Clear();
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            matches.Add(item);
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Matches");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        var propertyChangedEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        this.PropertyChanged(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
    }
}
```

When I press a button in my application the HandleLoadListClicked method occurs. It is changing the directoryName variable to be what the content of the selected item is. The it goes to the property Matches and gets the new matches from the chosen directory. But the directory is on it's default state - "currentMatches". It never changes. Can you suggest what's wrong?

Comment: I have corrected the indentation of your source code. Please make sure to do that in future questions; reading unknown nested code blocks with a broken indentation is really difficult and discourages users on this site to even read your question.

Comment: So is the problem with the second line of the `HandleLoadListClicked` method and `directoryName` or if the problem in the `Matches` property? The title of the question makes reference to INotifyPropertyChanged, but the actual question doesn't mention this.

Comment: What is the value of `selectedItem` when it gets assigned to `directoryName`?

Comment: "The it goes to the property Matches" - actually, as far as I can tell from your code, it does not technically touch that property.

Comment: Yes, it is my mistake that Matches should be the Property not the variable. But even if I go to Matches the directory name is on it's default state as I have declared it. Even though I change it in the method, the debugger shows that when it goes to Matches it is on it's original state

Comment: I realized that when I call OnPropertyChanged my directoryName is initialized again in the beginning of the class. Is this normal?

Comment: Following on from the comment of O. R. Mapper...what is the value of `selectedItem` when you assign it to `directoryName`? How do you know that `directoryName` is being initialised again when calling the `OnPropertyChanged` method if the `directoryName` variable is never changed from it's original state? Can you confirm that `directoryName` does actually change at some point from it's original value?

Comment: Yes it changes when I assign it with the value of selectedItem. I has another value. But when I use the debugger I see that after I go to OnPropertyChanged("Matches"), the variable directoryName is initialized again with it's default value in the beginning of the class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need one of this change

```
private void HandleLoadListClicked(object obj)
{
    directoryName = selectedItem;
    this.Matches = DataGetterAndSetter.GetMatches("Lists\\" + directoryName + ".xml");
    MainPage window = new MainPage();
    window.Show();
}
```

or

```
private void HandleLoadListClicked(object obj)
{
    directoryName = selectedItem;
    matches = DataGetterAndSetter.GetMatches("Lists\\" + directoryName + ".xml");
    MainPage window = new MainPage();
    window.Show();
    this.PropertyChanged(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
}
```

Comment: @user3523890 I would recommend the first option as looks like there is extra work going on in the setter of the `Matches` property. Whereas in the second option when the member variable `matches` is being set none of the work specified in the `Matches` property is being executed.

Comment: The first option might help but I realized that when I cal OnPropertyChanged my directoryName is initialized again in the beginning of the class. Is this normal?