# Variables being initialized again when INotifyPropertyChanged is used

Tags: wpf

Is it normal for global variables to be declared and initialized again when I call OnPropertyChanged("Something") ?
For example I have this code:

```
private ObservableCollection<MatchesViewModel> matches;
private ObservableCollection<string> listWithLists;
private string directoryName = "currentMatches";

private void HandleLoadListClicked(object obj)
{
    directoryName = selectedItem;
    this.Matches = DataGetterAndSetter.GetMatches("Lists\\" + directoryName + ".xml");
    MainPage window = new MainPage();
    window.Show();
}

public IEnumerable<MatchesViewModel> Matches
{
    get
    {
        matches = DataGetterAndSetter.GetMatches("Lists\\"+ directoryName + ".xml");
        return this.matches;
    }
    set
    {
        if (matches == null)
        {
            matches = new ObservableCollection<MatchesViewModel>();
        }
        matches.Clear();
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            matches.Add(item);
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Matches");
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        var propertyChangedEventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
        this.PropertyChanged(this, propertyChangedEventArgs);
    }
}
```

Every time when OnPropertyChanged("Matches") is ommited the directoryName variable is being initialized again in the beginning in the class with it's default value - "currentMatches". Is that normal and how can I save the value of directoryName in order to use it later when I get the data in the property?

Comment: No, that is not normal. Can you use stepwise execution to find out what exactly is executed when `OnPropertyChanged` is invoked (i.e. what event handlers are registered with the `PropertyChanged` event)?

Comment: When i use the debugger I see that it goes again in the beginning of the class and initializes all variables with their default values. Do you want the whole code?

Comment: Is this not the same problem being discussed here [Variable not changing on INotifyPropertyChanged WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23594845/variable-not-changing-on-inotifypropertychanged-wpf)?

Comment: @user3523890 I don't understand your code. Every time in getter you recreate whole list. Either you don't need setter, but then something else should notify that `Matches` needs to be refreshed, or getter should just return `this.Matches` without recreating the list